# refactoring, using super and defining

Tags: java, this, super

I have one parent class. But my issue is with the 2 subclasses and its superclass. I cannot get true access from the subclasses to allow the returning and printing when I run the program.

The issue lies in defining name and email and inserting what I feel should be the use of "super" as well. I don't know where they should all be going to get the program to run. At the moment it allows me to add name and email but shows blank when I run print.

So I need to know a way of defining this.email = email and this.name = name and using super to access getName and getEmail.

Very new at this, so any help would be much appreciated.

**SUPERCLASS -**

```
public class Member {

    private String email;

    private String name;


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

---

**SUBCLASS 2 -**

```
class Teacher extends Member {

    private String qualifications;


    public Teacher(String name, String email, String qualifications) {
        super.getName();
        super.getEmail();
        this.qualifications = qualifications;
    }


    public String getQualifications() {
        return qualifications;
    }


    public String toString() {

        StringBuffer details = new StringBuffer();
        details.append(super.getName());
        details.append(' ');

        if (qualifications != null && qualifications.trim().length() > 0) {
            details.append("(" + qualifications + ")");
            details.append(' ');
        }
        details.append(super.getEmail());
        return details.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend that you learn more about java inheritance. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

If you had constructor for your superclass which would look like this

```
public Member(String name, String email)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
```

you would be able to use something like this in you subclasses :

```
public Student(String name, String email)
   {
    super(name, email);
    this.attendance = 0;
   }
```

So when you write `Student mark = new Student("Mark", "Mark@example.org")`, you will be able to call `mark.getName()` which will return his name, but won't assign it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to use proper naming convention for member variable.

```
private String email;
private String name;
```

could be

```
private String sEmail;
private String sName;
```

Now, coming to your question, you need to add setter method for `email` and `name` in `Member` class.

For example :

```
public void setName (String strName)
{
   this.sName = strName;
}
```

**Or**

You can use arg-constructor to initialize both member variables

```
public Member(String strName, String strEmail)
{
    this.sName = strName;
    this.sEmail = strEmail;
}
```

Comment: Fine. Though the convention of using prefixes (like `s` and `str` above) is rare in java; I would almost say outdated, as it was a practice from earlier languages.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It was typo :D

Comment: @JoopEggen As per this document, I think, we need to use same http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: thanks for the feedback. When I was C++ programmer several conventions existed side-by-side, and the reduction in Java has been refreshing, especially in more complex heterogeneous systems.